# I messed things with ccsm

Tags: ccsm

Well, I'm a newbie.
I installed 11.10, and set a number of things till perfection.
Then I decided to make my OS "cool" by using ccsm, guess what??

"disappear they have"

symptoms:
- I cant see the toolbar that used to be in the left;

- Alt+F2 does not call the terminal;
- Ctrl+Shift+N creates a folder in the desktop (I think it used to do something different);
- The icons on the top-right disappear (all);
- I can now see File, Edit, View, Go, Bookmarks, Help on the top left;
- The change of workspaces shows like flipping the screen;

Sooo, I cannot get to the terminal to call ccsm and try to fix it!
I tried login with a Guest user and things were much worst, the screen would have an od behavior with parts of it disappearing during use.

I can still login by choosing Ubuntu2D, where things look normal (but with no effects I think)

How can I get my normal Ubuntu (rather than Ubuntu 2d) to work again?

(not sure but I think whatever I did had something to do with me messing with "Ubuntu Unity Plugin")

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue today. Simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for terminal, then `unity --reset`. After that enter `ccsm` and switch the Unity plugin on. That did the trick for me as well.

Comment: In case Ctrl+Alt+T won't work, you can press Ctrl+Alt+F1, log in, and run `(DISPLAY=:0.0 unity --reset &)` and then go back to the desktop with Ctrl+Alt+F7. It's also noteworthy, that you will lose all your Compiz settings by resetting the Unity profile.