# How do I fix a blank desktop after logging into regular Ubuntu (Unity)?

Tags: unity, compiz, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Ever since I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 my computer basically has been really screwed up. Loading up ubuntu in regular mode has a blank screen with my background and that's it, and so i'm in 2D mode.

Comment: You need to give more information. “Basically been really screwed up” is not informative. What happens when you type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in a terminal`? Copy-paste the output.

Comment: it asks for my password, which I can't give because it doesn't allow me to type it (the letters don't appear)

Comment: It's normal for the letters not to appear: passwords are not shown, in case someone was looking over your shoulder. What happens if you type your password and press Enter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to your "my desktop is blank in Unity (3D)" is simple, but involves using an advanced tool, Compiz Config Settings Manager.

---

> **Warning:** [*Compiz Config Settings Manager* is an advanced tool and one tiny mistake, typo or an accidental click of the mouse can leave your desktop unusable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it), requiring time and effort to fix it. Please be very careful and follow instructions...thanks. Once you are done using it, please consider uninstalling/removing it to reduce future risk. **If you mess up, please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70836/58612) on how to fix things.**

---

- Install *CompizConfig Settings Manager* with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` in Ubuntu 2D, if you don't already have it.
- Logout and log in **into Ubuntu (3D)**
- Right click on the blank desktop, create a new folder.
- Click on "File System" on the left sidebar, and navigate to `/usr/bin`. Scroll down to CCSM and double-click to run it:

  [image]
- Type `unity` in the Filter box and click on the Unity Plugin:

  [image]
- Just check the "Enable..." box on the bottom left and you should have your normal 3D environment back:

  [image]

Comment: When I try to install the first thing it asks for my password but when I type the password in the terminal it doesn't appear

Comment: The password **is never shown for sudo**, even as `*****`. Just type it and press enter!

Comment: the box was already "enabled" but I don't have my 3d environment back, what's the problem?

Comment: Can you open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`? Try `unity --reset` then.

Comment: One thing that should always be done when recommending CCSM is to warn the user (especially new ones) that this app can be dangerous, and should be used carefully, without experimenting with things that are unknown.

Comment: @MartyFried, many thanks for the reminder, agree completely, see bold warning added on top :)