# How do I disable or change the " Alt+` " shortcut to switch between multiple windows of a single application?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

On Ubuntu 12.04, how do I disable or change the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut which lets you switch between multiple windows of a single application? (see below for Terminal example)

My Windows VM in Korean needs to use that keyboard combination to switch character sets.

[image]

Comment: You can refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key , and to MODs possible duplicate.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/169836/50523

Answer (score 4):

> This appears to be a bug in Compiz (Unity's window manager), in that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcuts should appear in its shortcut list, but instead they show as disabled.

#### To disable (or change) the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between multiple windows of one application:

1. [Click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) to install the *Compiz Settings Manager* (CCSM) using the Software Center

   - Or install it from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` from the terminal
2. Start it from the Dash or by typing `ccsm` from the terminal.

   > **Statutory Warning:** *Compiz Config Settings Manager* is an advanced tool and one tiny mistake, typo or an accidental click of the mouse can leave your desktop unusable, requiring time and effort to fix it. Please be very careful and follow instructions...thanks. **If you mess up, please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/70836/58612) on how to fix things.**
3. Type "Unity" in the filter box on the left, and click on the Ubuntu Unity Plugin:

   [image]
4. Click on the Switcher Tab on top, and

   [image]

   - Look for the *Key to flip through windows in the switcher* entry near the bottom (scroll down if necessary)
   - Click on the <kbd>Disabled</kbd> button next to it
   - Check the *Enabled* box on the "Edit Key" popup
   - The keys will show, and click on the <kbd>Grab key combination</kbd> button
   - Press any keyboard shortcut combination (it doesn't matter, unless you want to remap this behavior to another shortcut); this will appear beneath the box.
   - Click on OK, and this shortcut will now show in place of the *Disabled* button
   - **Now click this button *again***, uncheck the *Enabled* box, and click on OK so that the shortcut again shows *Disabled*.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is now disabled. To also disable the reverse <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut, repeat step 4 for the *Key to flip through windows in the switcher* entry.

Finally, close CCSM and if you no longer need it, please consider uninstalling it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change the shortcut in Windows? Mine defaults to Left Alt+Shift to switch keyboard languages. Control Panel > Region and Language > Keyboards and Languages tab > Change keyboards button > Advanced Key Settings tab > select Between input languages (the current key is shown on the right side) > click the Change Key Sequence button to change the shortcut that Windows uses