# Key for switching between windows of the same application

Tags: 12.04, compiz, shortcut-keys

I am wondering where the keyboard short cut for switching between windows of the same application is defined. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
Currently I can press Alt+| to switch between windows.

In System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Navigation I have the following screenshot

[image]

As seen, there is no item for the **current** window, whereas there is an item for "Switch windows of an application", which is disabled.

Pressing and holding down the "Super" key shows that "Alt+|" is bound to "Switch windows of current application"..

In "CompizConfig Settings Manager->Window Management->Static Application Switcher" I get the following screenshot:

[image]

As seen, there is no key bound to "Next Window(group)"..

I find this rather confusing..

- What is the relation between Compiz and "System Settings->Keyboard"?
- Why is the key not showing up in either Compiz nor "System Settings"?
- How can I (preferably) change the keyboard setting for this task?

See also: 
[How do I disable or change the " Alt+` " shortcut to switch between multiple windows of a single application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168265/how-do-i-disable-or-change-the-alt-shortcut-to-switch-between-multiple-win)